# How to add HTML5 output tag data into MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, html

At this moment i have a HTML5 output tag , which provides some calculation.

For Example

```
<form oninput="totalScore.value = (+num1.value)*(+num2.value);">
    <input type="number" id="num1" />
    <input type="number" id="num2" />
<br />
    <output name="totalScore" for="num1 num2"></output>
</form>
```

`Now i want to use the output totalscore into a mysql query . 
How can i do that ?

Comment: Using HTML5 form tag, and handle your post data using backend server.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" id="numform" oninput="result.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">0
<input type="range" id="a" name="a" value="50">100
+<input type="number" id="b" name="b" value="50">
<br><br>
<input type="submit">
<p>The output element below is outside the form, but still a part of it.</p>
<input type="text" form="numform" name="result" for="a b">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Form submit output array**

```
Array ( [a] => 83 [b] => 50 [result] => 133 )
```

You can use this array into MySQL query

Comment: My Q is that , how can i use totalScore output data into a php variable . Just by using $_GET or $_POST